# The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties C#

Tags: c#, monodevelop, ambiguous

While compiling my program (I compile it from MonoDevelop IDE) I receive an error:

> Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   `System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ThreadStart)' and`
>   System.Threading.Thread.Thread(System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart)'
>   (CS0121)

Here the part of code.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate {
    try
    {
        Helper.CopyFolder(from, to);
        Helper.RunProgram("chown", "-R www-data:www-data " + to);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Helper.DeactivateThread(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
    Helper.DeactivateThread(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
});
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
thread.Name = name;
thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`delegate { ... }` is a an anonymous method that can be assigned to **any** delegate type, including `ThreadStart` and `ParameterizedThreadStart`.  Since the Thread Class provides constructor overloads with both argument types, it's ambiguous which constructor overload is meant.

`delegate() { ... }` (note the parenthesis) is a an anonymous method that takes no arguments. It can be assigned **only** to delegate types that take no arguments, such as `Action` or `ThreadStart`.

So, change your code to

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate() {
```

if you want to use the `ThreadStart` constructor overload, or to

```
Thread thread = new Thread(delegate(object state) {
```

if you want to use the `ParameterizedThreadStart` constructor overload.

Answer (score 2):

This error is thrown when you have a method that has overloads and your usage could work with either overload. The compiler isn't sure which overload you want to call so you need to explicitly state it by casting the parameter. One way to do this is like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate {
    try
    {
        Helper.CopyFolder(from, to);
        Helper.RunProgram("chown", "-R www-data:www-data " + to);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Helper.DeactivateThread(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
    Helper.DeactivateThread(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a lambda:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        Helper.CopyFolder(from, to);
        Helper.RunProgram("chown", "-R www-data:www-data " + to);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Helper.DeactivateThread(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }
    Helper.DeactivateThread(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
});

thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
thread.Name = name;
thread.Start();
```